# str.toUpperCase() is not able to convert the first character to upperCase in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript, string

I tried the below code in JavaScript:

```
console.log(str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(str[0], str[0].toUpperCase()));
```

**Case 1 - str = 'variable':**

```js
const str = 'variable';
console.log(str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(str[0], str[0].toUpperCase()));
```

It gives the expected output which is, **'Variable'**, i.e, the first letter of the string is in uppercase.

**Case 2 - str = 'Variable':**

```js
const str = 'Variable';
console.log(str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(str[0], str[0].toUpperCase()));
```

It gives the a strange output- **'variable'**.

I am quite new to JavaScript and am unable to understand what the reason is for this behavior.

```js
const str = 'Variable';
console.log(str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(str[0], str[0].toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: The first parameter of `replace()` is basically the search pattern. So by using `str[0]` there you're telling `replace` to replace whatever the first character of the original string is. Unless it's a lowercase character, that won't work.

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisG The link you provided solves his problem, but he is trying to understand **what is** the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: @Zakk True, which is why I explained the reason in my comment above. I guess you're arguing it's not really a dupe of that other question and I might agree if we didn't also have [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a constant, and a string (strings are immutable); it is always

```
const str = 'Variable';
```

If you take `str[0]`, you get `V`.

So, `.toLowerCase().trim().replace(str[0]` will never match if the first character is upper-case, because the upper-case `str[0]` will not be contained inside the trimmed, lower-cased string.

I'd save the lower-cased version of the string in a variable first, so you can access *that* string's `[0]`.

```js
const str = 'Variable';
const lower = str.toLowerCase().trim();
console.log(lower.replace(lower[0], lower[0].toUpperCase()));
```

Or, to be more precise, extract only the first character, upper-case it, and lower-case the rest.

```js
const str = 'Variable';
const result = (
  str[0].toUpperCase() +
  str.slice(1).toLowerCase()
);
console.log(result);
```